# How can a user written program be send to library?

Tags: java, file, file-io, shared-libraries, delete-file

I tried a code.

Well, the first part is the main method that basically lays down the directory structure. I tried to delete a directory that contains other directories using the rmdirs method I wrote below.

```
public static void rmdirs(File k)
{
    String[] y= k.list();
    int i;
    File f;

    for(i=0;i<y.length;i++)
    {
        f= new File(k,y[i]);
        if(f.isDirectory() && f.list().length>0)
        {
            rmdirs(f);
        }
        else
        {
            f.delete();
        }
    }
    k.delete();
}
```

The rmdirs method is working and seems to be doing what I expected, but how do I add this program to a library, so that I can repeatedly use it by importing something.

Also, the above program does something like

```
rmdirs(f2);
```

to delete a file.
I would like it to be something like

```
f2.rmdirs();
```

And I am wondering how I can do it. I tried somehting like

```
import java.io.*;
public class RFile extends File
{

    public RFile(String p)
    {
        super(p);

    }
    public RFile(File f1,String p1)
    {
        super(f1,p1);

    }
    public void rmdirs()
    {
        RFile k=this;
        String[] y= k.list();
        int i;
        RFile f;

        for(i=0;i<y.length;i++)
        {
            f= new RFile(k,y[i]);
            if(f.isDirectory() && f.list().length>0)
            {
                f.rmdirs();
            }
            else
            {
                f.delete();
            }
        }
        k.delete();
    }
}
```

But then, the tester class or main class becomes one in which I have to use RFile and not File.
This is a  problem; Also, like I asked before, how do I add all these to a library so that importing `java.io.RFile` or something like that will do the job?

Answer (score 1):

You don't extend java.io.File (unless you have a **very** good reason and this is not such a reason)

One solution is to create a class like "FileUtils" which has a static method "remove" so you can call:

```
FileUtils.remove(myFile);
```

It's a general design philosophy that you can find in for example apache libraries (e.g. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

**UPDATE**

A library is simply a reusable collection of code with a specific purpose.

Apache is a foundation that manages a lot of open source projects (a lot if not all of it java-based). They provide high quality (though in a few cases outdated) software that can be reused. While you're at it you might want to take a peek at "apache maven" which handles the lifecycle of a project and makes library management easy (believe it or not there is a whole repository with more than 600.000 libraries in it for you to use: http://mvnrepository.com/

And this is just one (although the largest) repository...

Design philosophy is an enormous subject with as many opinions as there are coders. However there are some best practices that everyone adheres to.

Apache usually has pretty high quality code so you can check them if not for code, at least for a good way to write libraries. Other than that I can only point you towards books and google to find your way.

Writing maintainable code is more of an art than a science and it takes a lot of reading and practice to master it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The thing is - I know NOTHING about libraries. How can one create them or use them? What is a design philosophy? What exactly is commons.apache.org? I would like a little more  elaboration, possibly with detailed examples and/or instructions.

Comment: That right there takes a book to explain and experience to grasp. Suffice to say that apache is an organisation that provides a lot of open source libraries for common problems. Some of the software it provides it outdated, other is top notch.